# Need Suggestion for HTML

Tags: html

This code works perfectly fine but I have added two different search boxes for name and id is it possible to have a single search box redirect based on the datatype entered?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: yellow;
                text-align: center;
                font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
                font-size: 24px;
                margin-left: 150px;
                margin-right: 150px;
            }
            h1 {
                font-size: 60px;
            }
            p {
                font-size: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to Employee Database!</h1>
        <p>View <a href="http://localhost:8080/tyrrest/employees">Employee List</a>.</p>
        <p style="font-size: 20px;">Search Employee by ID</p>
        <form>
            <input id="id-input-text" type="text">
            <input class="thmas-button" type="button" value="Search" data-search-type="id">
        </form>
        <p style="font-size: 20px;">Search Employee by Name</p>
        <form>
            <input id="name-input-text" type="text">
            <input class="thmas-button" type="button" value="Search" data-search-type="name">
        </form>
        <p style="font-size:12px;"><br><br><br><br><br><br><a href="http://localhost:8080/tyrrest/employees?fields=name">Employee Name List</a></p>
        <p style="font-size:12px;"><a href="http://localhost:8080/tyrrest/employees?fields=id">Employee Id List</a></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            const thmasButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.thmas-button');
            thmasButtons.forEach(button => {
                button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    const searchType = button.getAttribute('data-search-type');
                    const inputValue = document.querySelector(`#${searchType}-input-text`).value;
                    const URL = `http://localhost:8080/tyrrest/employees?${searchType}=${inputValue}`;
                    const win = window.open(URL, '_blank');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How to do it based on data type?

Comment: You can use a searchtype selection combo or radio button to select either id or name.

Comment: it works based on datatype?

Comment: of course. because you select the datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the type of input in JS like this:
`Number.isFinite(Number(inputValue))`

basically we're casting inputValue to Number and checking if it's not `NaN` (yes, for JS `NaN` type is a number :) )

with sth like this: `const searchType = Number.isFinite(Number(inputValue)) ? 'id' : 'name';`

1. typing 'abc' will redirect to `employees?name=abc`
2. typing '123' will redirect to `employees?id=123`

your `body` converted to 1 search box:

```
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to Employee Database!</h1>
        <p>View <a href="http://localhost:8080/tyrrest/employees">Employee List</a>.</p>
        <p style="font-size: 20px;">Search Employee</p>
        <form>
            <input id="input-text" type="text">
            <input class="thmas-button" type="button" value="Search">
        </form>
        <p style="font-size:12px;"><br><br><br><br><br><br><a href="http://localhost:8080/tyrrest/employees?fields=name">Employee Name List</a></p>
        <p style="font-size:12px;"><a href="http://localhost:8080/tyrrest/employees?fields=id">Employee Id List</a></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            const thmasButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.thmas-button');
            thmasButtons.forEach(button => {
                button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    const inputValue = document.querySelector(`#input-text`).value;
                    const searchType = Number.isFinite(Number(inputValue)) ? 'id' : 'name';
                    const URL = `http://localhost:8080/tyrrest/employees?${searchType}=${inputValue}`;
                    const win = window.open(URL, '_blank');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```